# Indexes not used for join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index-tuning

I join `listings_tail` table and materialised view `cals_reviewed_wide_scaled` on `listing_id` column of type integer.

The table has around 1,5 billion rows and 2 mln unique listing ids. The MV has been tested with a range from 500 to 500 000 rows. Both columns are indexed with btree, hash, and brin.

`explain` always returns `Seq Scan` despite of the indexes available.

How to optimize the indexing to make them work?

#### query

```
SELECT * from listings_tail L
INNER JOIN cals_reviewed_wide_scaled R 
ON L.listing_id = R.listing_id;
```

#### tables

```
\d listings_tail

 id                   | bigint                      | not null default nextval('listings_tail_id_seq'::regclass)
 listing_id           | integer                     | not null
 parsing_timestamp    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 value                | character varying           | not null
 homes_details_inside | integer                     | not null
 tags                 | character varying[]         | not null
Indexes:
    "listings_tail_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "listings_tail_dd_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (listing_id, value, homes_details_inside, tags)
    "listing_id_tail" btree (listing_id)
    "tail_listing_id_brin" brin (listing_id)
    "tail_listing_id_hash" hash (listing_id)
```

---

```
\d cals_reviewed_wide
 id                | integer                     | not null default nextval('cals_reviewed_wide_id_seq'::regclass)
 listing_id        | integer                     | not null
 date              | timestamp without time zone | not null
 price             | double precision            |
 parsing_timestamp | timestamp without time zone | not null
 min_nights        | double precision            |
 max_nights        | double precision            |
 available         | integer                     | not null
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 revs_id           | integer                     | not null
Indexes:
    "cals_reviewed_wide_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "cals_reviewed_wide_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (listing_id, date)
    "cals_reviewed_wide_revs_id_ixs" btree (revs_id)
    "ix_cals_reviewed_wide_listing_id" btree (listing_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "cals_reviewed_wide_revs_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (revs_id) REFERENCES reviews(id)
```

---

```
\d random_cals_reviewed_wide_scaled

View "public.random_cals_reviewed_wide_scaled"
 Column  |  Type  | Modifiers
---------+--------+-----------
 revs_id | bigint |
```

---

```
\d cals_reviewed_wide_scaled
Materialized view "public.cals_reviewed_wide_scaled"

-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 listing_id        | integer                     |
 date              | timestamp without time zone |
 price             | double precision            |
 parsing_timestamp | timestamp without time zone |
 min_nights        | double precision            |
 max_nights        | double precision            |
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone |
 revs_id           | integer                     |
Indexes:
    "cals_reviewed_wide_scaled_listing_id_brin" brin (listing_id)
    "cals_reviewed_wide_scaled_listing_id_hash" hash (listing_id)
    "cals_reviewed_wide_scaled_listing_id_ixs" btree (listing_id)
```

#### materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cals_reviewed_wide_scaled
      as 
      SELECT 
       C.listing_id, 
       C.date, 
       C.price,
       C.parsing_timestamp,
       C.min_nights,
       C.max_nights,
       C.created_at,
       C.revs_id
       FROM cals_reviewed_wide as C
       JOIN random_cals_reviewed_wide_scaled as V
       ON C.revs_id = V.revs_id;
```

#### explain

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

[image]

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112664/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dmitriy-grankin).

Answer (score 2):

Both tables are not small, and you have no `WHERE` condition that restricts the number of rows in either table.

`work_mem` is big enough to contain the hash of `cals_reviewed_wide_scaled`, so the most efficient plan is a hash join.

With a hash join, [no index can be used](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/join-strategies-and-performance-in-postgresql/), and a sequential scan is the most efficient access method.

---

You can try if a nested loop join might be faster.

For that, make sure that there is an index on `listings_tail.listing_id`, then try the following to nudge PostgreSQL in the right direction:

- Try increasing `effective_cache_size` to the amount of RAM you have got.
- Try lowering `random_page_cost` to `1.0`.
- If all fails, experiment with setting the following *in your database session*:

  ```
  SET enable_hashjoin = off;
  SET enable_mergejoin = off;
  ```

  Then try again, and you should see a nested loop join. That way you can test if that is actually faster and PostgreSQL is wrong.

Comment: Discussion on this post has been added to the [existing chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112664/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dmitriy-grankin).